# Is there a media player that works on HTTPS sites?

Tags: https, audio

I'm currently using Yahoo! Media Player for a site that needs to play MP3 files that are stored on our server. In total, there's quite a bit more than the free limits at Soundcloud, but each file is only a few minutes long.

YMP is pretty good, but causes security warnings on HTTPS pages, because it can only be served via HTTP.

Is there an equivalent free player I can embed for the HTTPS pages?

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, I'm initially looking for something that will scan the page and turn media links playable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it has problem(s) with HTTPS but maybe you can do a try with [soundmanager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/). I used this library and I think it's great.

Comment: Looks good, but the great thing about YMP-style players is that they add a "play" button to every linked MP3 on the page; no extra coding. I'd like to see if there is a similar thing I can get without doing the coding myself, first.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this MP3 player from internoetics.com](http://www.internoetics.com/2011/01/18/automatically-convert-mp3-links-to-audio-players/); it's somewhat simpler than Yahoo! Media Player, but it works the same way, and you can install it locally so there shouldn't be any issues with HTTPS.

There's also a locally installable [mod of the old del.icio.us playtagger](http://hearingvoices.com/news/2011/10/playtagger-mod/), which works the same way.  Then there's [Streampad](http://www.streampad.com/), which has a slightly different interface; alas, it doesn't seem to be installable locally, and while the script *can* be loaded over HTTPS, it doesn't seem to be an intended usage mode and gives an ugly security warning due to an invalid certificate.

One more option for local install might be the venerable [NiftyPlayer](http://www.varal.org/media/niftyplayer/) and its [FlashMP3alizer](http://www.varal.org/media/niftyplayer/flashmp3alizer.html) script.  It's kind of old and primitive, and the popup window interface IMO sucks, but apparently it can be configured not to do that.  And at least it's stable.

**Edit:** Two more options: [1 Bit Audio Player](http://1bit.markwheeler.net/) and [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/).  Both are open source and support making all MP3 links on the page playable.

Answer (score -2):

Can you just embed the mediaplayer script via https?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/js"></script>
```

Comment: -1 Did you actually [try that](https://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/js) before suggesting?